# How to trigger end of search or nohlsearch was called

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting, neovim

I have the following code inside my vimrc

```
hi CurrentWordUL cterm=underline gui=underline
hi Search cterm=underline ctermfg=124 gui=underline guifg=#af0000

augroup MyHighlighter
  autocmd!
  " autocmd User IncSearchEnter MatchHighlighter 0
  " autocmd User IncSearchExecute MatchHighlighter 1

  set updatetime=700
  autocmd CursorHold * if (get(g:, 'matchhl', 1) && (&ft !~ join(g:ft_blacklist, '\|')))
\ | silent! exe printf('match CurrentWordUL /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))
\ | endif
  autocmd CursorMoved * if (get(g:, 'matchhl', 1) && (&ft !~ join(g:ft_blacklist, '\|')))
\ | silent! exe printf('match none')
\ | endif
augroup END

nnoremap <silent> <f4> :MatchHighlighter<CR>
command! -nargs=? MatchHighlighter
\  call ToggleSetMatchHL(
\  empty(<q-args>) ? !get(g:, 'matchhl', 1) : expand(<q-args>))

function! ToggleSetMatchHL(arg) abort
match none | diffupdate | syntax sync fromstart
let g:matchhl = a:arg
endfunction
```

The purpose of this is to highlight (underline)  matching word under the cursor.

The issue I have is when I'm searching with /, ?, *, # etc. The matching highlight overwrite the search highlight.

Is there anyway I can know "end of search" (I don't know the definition of "end of search" but maybe someone can suggest something) or "nohlsearch" was called?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no I don't think so. Some plugins implement similar logic, however, they overwrite the whole search command f.e. (https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you switch from `:match` to `:call matchadd(...)`, you can specify a `{priority}`. A negative one will put the highlighting *below* the search highlighting (which has prio `0`; default is `10`).
- There's no event for "end of search". You could override all search-related commands (`/`, `?`, `*`, etc); that would detect a *start* of search. For `/` and `?`, you could define a `cmap <CR>` with a check of `getcmdtype() =~# '[/?]'` to detect the conclusion of a search. I wouldn't recommend this approach; the mappings may interfere with other plugins.
- Instead of using `:match` (which is window-local, so the highlighting also behaves differently than the built-in search highlighting), you could automatically adapt the current search pattern (register `/`) instead. My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) chooses this approach with its `:SearchAutoHighlighting` command. (The plugin page has links to many alternative plugins you may want to check out; I would prefer a well-maintained plugin over a custom code snippet in my `~/.vimrc`.)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I will do my research from here.